# cant get radio button onchange to work in cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I dont get any output for my onchange event for a radio button.
I want to select 3 out of 4 a radio buttons and disable a text input field and the other enables the text input.

Currently I cant get it to output anything.

```
echo $this->Form->input('startDate',array('id'=>'startdatebox','label' => 'Start Date','class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text','style'=>'width:100px;height:30px','value' => $datestart));

  ..

echo $this -> Form -> input('dateRange', 
               array('id'=>'dateRange2','label' => '<h6>Date Range</h6>','type' => 'radio', 
                 'value' =>$dateSelect,'name'=>'dateRange2' ,'options' =>  $selectoption))
```

;

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("input[name='data[User][dateRange2]']").on("click",function() {
 $('#startdatebox, #enddatebox').prop('disabled', $(this).val()  != 3);
  alert( 'aasda');
});
```

Comment: There is no change event in your code. Please either correct your title/question or complete your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onChange() is not working for radio button, but it works for checkbox or select.

In order to detect the select action for radios, you have to use onclick() function instead. As Supravat's answer, you need to pass "this.value" in the onclick() function, and you get the selected value in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

First call `onclick`  on your radio button, as like

```
echo $this -> Form -> input('dateRange', 
  array('id'=>'dateRange2',
      'label' => '<h6>Date Range</h6>',
      'type' => 'radio', 
      'value' =>$dateSelect,
      'name'=>'dateRange2' ,
      'options' =>  $selectoption, 
      'onclick'=> 'myFunc(this.value)'
     )
);
```

Then Add javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc(val) {
    if(val != 3) {
        document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("startdatebox").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("enddatebox").disabled = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

**Or, to change the disabled property of input fields using jQuery 1.6 +**

```
 function myFunc(val) {
      $('#startdatebox, #enddatebox').prop('disabled', $(this).val()  != 3);
 }
```

I hope you may help it.